# String comparison - JDK versions produce different results

Tags: string, java, java-7, java-6

I've implemented a basic Guava predicate:

```
containsPatternIgnoreCase(@Nullable final String input) {
   checkNotNull(input);
   return new Predicate<String>() {
       @Override
       public boolean apply(@Nullable String current) {
           checkNotNull(current);
           return current.toLowerCase(ENGLISH).contains(input.toLowerCase(ENGLISH));
       }
   };
}
```

All is fine, but ONE test case fails on Travis:

```
assertThat(containsPatternIgnoreCase("TURKİYE").apply("turkiye güzel")).isTrue();
```

I took care of not inheriting from the default locale in my implementation, so I really wonder what can be wrong there. Could it depend on the JDK versions?

Here is what's used on my machine:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-10M4406)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)
```

And on Travis CI:

```
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!
Rolf

Comment: `System.out.println("turkiye güzel".toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains("TURKİYE".toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));` prints `false` on my machine (JDK 1.7.0_17). Maybe someone can try with a JDK 6.

Comment: Hmmm, I really don't know what the logical result should be. :-(

Comment: actually this: `System.out.println("TURKİYE".toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));` prints `turki̇'ye` (not with a real quote but can't insert the actual character here)

Comment: But how come the same instruction produces "turkiye" on my machine? I don't get it. No default locale is retrieved at any time, or is it? What is system-dependent here?

Comment: I really suspect this is a breaking change somewhere deep in the JDK :P Setting OpenJDK 6 on Travis solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casefolding is a complicated problem, and it is apparently not possible to get is "right" unless you use the right locale.

This W3 page deals with this:  http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding

Yes, you probably have found a JDK dependency here.  But the fix is probably not to expect case-folding to be consistent if the locale doesn't match the language of the text (or text fragment) you are processing.

Comment: I indeed do *NOT* expect an optimal solution, but a stable one. That doesn't seem to be the case here :-(

Comment: It is stable ... for a given JRE and library and operating system and computer, it will return the same result. The whole mechanism of using locales was created to provide stable results across computers and international boundaries.

Comment: Well, what you describe is true. However, it should be stable for all JREs (at least from one specific vendor), don't you think?

Comment: @Rolf - It would be nice.  But we can't put a finger exactly on what changed and (more important) why.  And if you don't know why it changed it is hard to make the call that it shouldn't have changed.  (Generally speaking there is a good reason for each "breaking" change that is made to Java.)

Comment: You can't expect stability AND have bug fixes.

Comment: @nilskp - Indeed, one man's "important bug fix" is another man's "breaking change".  If stability is your overriding concern, then don't upgrade.  Ever.

Comment: The obvious corollary is that stability normally *shouldn't be* your overriding concern.  In many / most contexts, ensuring that you are up-to-date with security patches is more important.  (If not for you, then at least for most people who run your software.)